# How to map the actor with replies in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

This is my REST API to get my news,

```
http://Mydomain/_api/social.feed/my/news
```

I get response. My sample response are,

```
<d:Threads m:type="Collection(SP.Social.SocialThread)">
      <d:element>
              <d:Actors m:type="Collection(SP.Social.SocialActor)">
                 <d:element>
                    <d:AccountName>USER1</d:AccountName>
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             .


                 <d:element> 
                 <d:element>
                    <d:AccountName>USER2</d:AccountName>
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             .


                 <d:element>
                 <d:element>
                    <d:AccountName>USER3</d:AccountName>
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             .


                 <d:element>
             </d:Actors>
      <d:element>

      <d:Replies m:type="Collection(SP.Social.SocialPost)">
                  <d:element>
                     <d:Attachment m:null="true" />
                        .
                        .
                        .

                     <d:Text>Reply1</d:Text>

                  </d:element> 

                  <d:element>
                     <d:Attachment m:null="true" />
                        .
                        .
                        .

                     <d:Text>Reply2</d:Text>

                  </d:element> 

                  <d:element>
                     <d:Attachment m:null="true" />
                        .
                        .
                        .

                     <d:Text>Reply3</d:Text>

                  </d:element> 

                   <d:element>
                     <d:Attachment m:null="true" />
                        .
                        .
                        .

                     <d:Text>Reply4</d:Text>

                  </d:element> 

                  <d:element>
                     <d:Attachment m:null="true" />
                        .
                        .
                        .

                     <d:Text>Reply5</d:Text>

                  </d:element> 
      </d:Replies>

 <d:Threads>
```

My Aim is to display like this

USER2 posted  Reply3; 
USER3 Posted  Reply4

But here How do I map the actor to replies? 
There is no id or other attribute is common between author and replies.